# I want to show that the following two terms approach $0$ with increasing $N$.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

I want to show that the following two terms approach $0$ with increasing $N$.

$$2f(N-1)/(N-1) \sum_{s=1}^{N-2} 1/s$$
&
$$2 \sum_{q<N-1} (f(q)/q) \sum_{s=1}^{q} 1/(N-s)$$

Here $f(n)$ is a monotone decreasing function with $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a discussion then a solution. I don't think your second limit goes to zero since
\begin{align}
\sum^q_{s=1} \frac{1}{N-s}\sim \log\left(\frac{N-1}{N-q} \right)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\sum^{N-2}_{q= 1} \frac{f(q)}{q}\sum^q_{s=1}\frac{1}{N-s} \sim \sum^{N-2}_{q=1} \frac{f(q)}{q}\log\left(\frac{N-1}{N-q}\right).
\end{align}
If you just consider your sum from for $1\leq q<N/2$, you'll see
\begin{align}
 \sum^{N/2}_{q=1}\frac{f(q)}{q}\log\left(\frac{N-1}{N-q} \right)\sim \sum^{N/2}_{q=1} \frac{c}{q}\log\left(\frac{N}{2} \right)\sim (\log N)^2.
\end{align}

Edit: I believe you could make the argument rigorous to make $(\log N)^2$ a lower bound.

Comment: How if we decompose the last term into two summations, $$\sum_{q<N-1} =\sum_{q<q_{0}} - \sum_{q=q_{0}}^{N-2}$$ ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: How If we show that those two summations have upper bounds?

Comment: You mean $\sum_{q<N-1}$ has an upper bound?

Comment: Yes. How if we decompose the last term into two summations, $$\sum_{q<N-1} =\sum_{q<q_{0}}  +\sum_{q=q_{0}}^{N-2} <= C$$ ?

Comment: My "solution" shows that it's not bounded.

Comment: How about the below answer

Comment: Could you please explain me how you have written $ \sum^q_{s=1} \frac{1}{N-s}\sim \log\left(\frac{N-1}{N-q} \right)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

How if we choose $q_{0}$ large enough so that $f(q_{0})< \varepsilon$ and $N>2q_{0}^2$. Then

$$\sum_{q<q_{0}} \le f(1)\sum_{q<q_{0}}1/q \sum_{s=1}^q 1/(N/2) \le f(1)/q_{0}$$

and

$$\sum_{q=q_{0}}^{N-2} \le ...$$

Comment: First of all. Your limit tends to $c$ not zero.

Comment: If it tends to zero, then anything can happen.

Comment: Sorry, here $c=0$

Comment: So is it correct to show there is an upper bound?

Comment: My answer is that it depends how fast $f\rightarrow 0$

Comment: @JackyChong since $f$ is a decreasing function can we conclude that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47110/discussion-between-jacky-chong-and-oily).

Comment: Sorry I couldn't use it